# i using laravel-websockets and error Cannot read property 'socketId' of undefined

Tags: laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I do not use socket.io but it gives me such an error

app.js:18695 Uncaught TypeError: `Cannot read property 'socketId' of undefined`

I wrote in the details, I updated it, I had an SSL problem before, so I could not connect as https, this problem came out when I was dealing with it.

i this using
laravel-websockets,
pusher,
laravel echo

chat.blade.php

```
 var globalChannelId = 0;

var user_id = document.getElementById('user_id').value;

    function channel(elem) {
    
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: '{{ route('channelControl') }}',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {user_id: user_id, receiver_id: elem.id},
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status === 200) {
                    globalChannelId = data.data;
                    document.getElementById('channel_token').value = data.data;
                    document.getElementById('receiver_id').value = data.receiver_id;
    
                    var message = data.message;
                    console.log("message")
                    console.log(message)
    
                    var parentDiv = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
                    parentDiv.innerHTML = "";
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.classList = "d-flex";
                        var h6 = document.createElement('h6');
                        h6.innerHTML = message[i]["user"]["name"];
                        var span = document.createElement('span');
                        span.innerHTML = message[i]["message"];
                        div.appendChild(h6);
                        div.appendChild(span);
                        parentDiv.appendChild(div);
                    }
                    dinle()
                    scroll()
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

---

```
var dongu;
function dinle() {
    Echo.disconnect();
    Echo.connect();

    // Echo.leave('privatechat.5D707F5F-CAAF-A775-1FE5-E1EA94208A22');
    console.log(globalChannelId);
    Echo.join('privatechat.' + globalChannelId)
        .here((user) => {
                var activeUser = document.getElementById('activeUser');
                activeUser.innerHTML = "";
            console.log(user);
            console.log("here");
            for(var i=0 ; i<user.length ; i++){
                var h6 = document.createElement('h6');
                h6.innerHTML = user[i].name;
                h6.id=user[i].id;
                activeUser.appendChild(h6);
            }
        })
        .joining((user) => {
            console.log('joining')
            var activeUser = document.getElementById('activeUser');
            var h6 = document.createElement('h6');
            h6.innerHTML = user.name;
            h6.id=user.id;
            activeUser.appendChild(h6);
        })
        .leaving((user) => {
            console.log('Leaving');
            document.getElementById(user.id).innerHTML = "";
            console.log(user);
        })
        .listen('PrivateChannelSend', (e) => {
            console.log(e.message.message)
            console.log(e)
            var parentDiv = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.classList = "d-flex";
            var h6 = document.createElement('h6');
            h6.innerHTML = e.message["user"]["name"];
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = e.message["message"];
            div.appendChild(h6);
            div.appendChild(span);
            parentDiv.appendChild(div);
            scroll()

        })

    .listenForWhisper('typing',response => {
        console.log('typing');
        document.getElementById('yaziyor').style.display = "block";
        console.log(response);
        if(response){
            clearTimeout(dongu);
        }
        dongu = setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('yaziyor').style.display = "none";
            }, 3000);

    });
}
```

broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'), 
            'useTLS' => true,
            'encrypted' => true,
            'scheme' => 'https', 
            'debug' => true,
             'curl_options' => [
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

websockets.php

```
'ssl' => [ 
      'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'enable_client_messages' => true,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
        'encrypted' => true,
    ],
], 
    'local_cert' => '/usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/etc/live/sub.xsite.com.tr/fullchain.pem',
    'local_pk' => '/usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/etc/live/sub.xsite.com.tr/privkey.pem', 
    'passphrase' => null,
    'verify_peer' => false,
],
```

Comment: Welcome to SO .. can u show your code ?

Comment: friend i updated

Comment: remove ssl and check

Comment: There is no `socketId` in code you've posted. You should post part of code where error happened - where `socketId` is.

Comment: I don't use socket io, it happened after the "npm run dev" command

Comment: I deleted my SSL but it didn't work